# Eclipse Cpp g++ command not found (MinGW & CDT Installed)

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I am very new in using Eclipse as an IDE and I am facing many problems in configuring it. I may also be asking a few problems that may already be on forum but believe me I've tried almost all that I could have. SO coming towards the problem, I made a simple Hello World program for C++ to test out my config and YES I have installed MinGW and CDT. I have also edited the path environment variable for MinGW, and I chose MinGW GCC as toolchain while creating it and still my simple HELLO WORLD is giving me the error:

> /bin/sh: g++: command not found  make: *** [src/TEST2.o] Error 127

I have no idea what I have missed in between and it would be very helpful if someone would help me out correctly config my Eclipse :)

PS: I don't know if changing the tool(compiler) in Tool chain editor affects the process but I tried it as well...

Comment: Path of least resistance is to add the mingw bin folder to the system path and then rebooting the computer. There are likely less intrusive ways to get Eclipse to detect mingw, but brute force has  always worked for me in the past

Comment: @user4581301 Actually Eclipse does detects the MinGW as before changing the path environment variable, it gave a make not found error which got resolved after I added the path for its binaries in the variable, and yes I did reboot my system after doing that...

Comment: My apologies. `make` not found. `make` is not a part of gcc. For `make` you will have to install `msys2` or a similar toolkit.

Comment: @user4581301 Msys Installation did came with MinGW developer toolkit bin ...I actually installed the whole basic setup and it does includes Msys :)

Comment: Can you run `make` from a regular command prompt?

Comment: @user4581301 Well if I change the directory to that of msys then yes...however it will just show makefile not found (plus I may not have understood what you said as I am very new to this, i don't have much knowledge of setting up compilers)

Comment: I haven't used Windows in a long time, but my recollection is that MSYS has its own `PATH` distinct from the Windows system `PATH`, so the problem may be that the directory containing `g++.exe` is not in the MSYS `PATH`.

Comment: (Note: based on the error message, it's `g++` that can't be found, not `make`. The `make: *** [src/TEST2.o] Error 127` part was likely on a separate line, and gets output any time an error occurs while running a makefile.)

Comment: @HighCommander4 Yess...it is in a separate line and the problem is I don't know why there's a  g++ command not found error even after installing and setting everything up exactly as described by eclipse forum itself